# How to embed JavaFX8 in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, javafx-8

I want to use components from Javafx8 in eclipse but eclipse can't find FXCanvas in JDK. Rest of javaFX classes are found. Creating plugin from jfxswt.jar doesnt work because i got errors like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.Parent cannot be found
```

during compilation. Any ideas?

Comment: I created, plugin from jfxrt.jar and it is working. I thought that I will not need a plugin with jfxrt.jar as that javafx is now an integral part of the jdk.